# Why is the bottom of my fragment not displaying?

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I created the following DialogFragment in XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@id/mainLayout"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/quoteLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/buttonLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/getMoreButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/getMore"
            android:onClick="getMore" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/adLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've been working along on the quoteLayout section and have it performing as I wish. Now I wanted to fill the other sections with a button and an ad.

The problem is that nothing still shows up in the other parts of the mainLayout. The end of the screen is the end of the quoteLayout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it orientation set as `vertical` but in your linearlayout children you have the `android:layout_height` attribute as `match_parent` which fills up the layout. It should be `wrap_content` or use `weights` to better organize how it should look. At least, that's what looks wrong to me. Try swapping out `match_parent` to `wrap_content` or use `weight` attribute. Note that if you use `weight` set `android:layout_height' to`0dp.`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@id/mainLayout"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="0dp"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@id/quoteLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@id/buttonLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@id/getMoreButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/getMore"
        android:onClick="getMore" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@id/adLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your quote layout to match_height within another LinearLayout that also matches height. Your button layout and adLayout are simply off the bottom of the screen.

To fix this, I would use layout weights like so:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@id/mainLayout"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/quoteLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/buttonLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="0.3"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/getMoreButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/getMore"
            android:onClick="getMore" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@id/adLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="0.2"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="0dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Notice that I have changed `layout_height` to `0dp` and added a `layout_weight` tag. This tag makes it so that your layout will adjust to a certain percentage of the height based on the values entered.

You could also use `wrap_content` for height.